# Apache2.4 mod_sed, how to use a variable in OutputSed

Tags: apache-2.4

Apache2.4, mod_sed

I am trying to use a variable instead of static text to make a sed command.

```
SetEnv MY_VAR TESTING
OutputSed "s|TEXT_TO_SEARCH|%{ENV:MY_VAR}|g"
```

But the TEXT_TO_SEARCH is replaced with the literal text **%{ENV:MY_VAR}**.
How can i use the variable?
Thank you.